# prevent color from overlapsing cell border

Tags: tables, color, multirow

All question I have looked to doesn't help me to solve my problem. Here's my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\mc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|p{7cm}|c|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\cellcolor{gray!30} \centering \bfseries Flux de\par substance étudié & 
\cellcolor{gray!30} \centering  \bfseries Mécanisme \par environnemental & 
\cellcolor{gray!30} \bfseries Unité & 
\multicolumn{1}{|p{7cm}|}{\cellcolor{gray!30} \centering \bfseries Remarques\par(RECORD)} \\
\cline{1-4}
\cellcolor{green!50}  & %
\cellcolor{green!50} \'Emission  de CO2 liée à l'épandage de chaux &
\cellcolor{green!50}  &
\\
\cline{2-2}
\cellcolor{green!50} \multirow{-2}{*}{CO2} & 
\cellcolor{green!50}![enter image description here][1] \'Emission  de CO2 liée à l'épandage d'urée &
\cellcolor{green!50} \multirow{-2}{*}{$kg/ha$} &
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I get :
[image]

Table cell color overlaps cell border but I want the borders to be always visible. The answers given to questions I read doesn't helped as the people who give the solution doesn't explain well the code they give.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I believe, this is rather a PDF viewer problem. I tested your code and after zooming in (tested on Linux Acrobat Reader 9.4) the borders where visible at all boundaries.

Comment: I tested it Adobe Reader 11 on Windows and it doesn't show but in evince the borders are shown. I thought that PDF is portable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a pdf viewer problem as stated in comments